# Shortest path with jumps (dynamic Bayesian network)?

Tags: path-connected, directed-graphs, bayesian-network, discrete-time

Suppose I have the following graph structure:

[image]

It has the following properties:

- There are four states $\mathcal{S} = {q,s_1,s_2,s_3}$ where $q$ is some origin state where we start from (though it is not time-indexed).
- The transition cost going from node $i$ to node $j$ is given by $c^t_{i,j}$ where $t$ is the time-stamp of the destination node. So for example: $c^2_{s_1,s_1}$ is the cost of travelling between $s_1$ at time $t=1$ and $s_1$ at time $t=2$.
- Each node (black dot) is shown with it's state-label and the time index of that state e.g. $(s_2,1)$ is state $s_2$ at time index $1$.

My interest is in finding the path with the lowest cost. I am not interested in the tour i.e., not the TSP (travelling salesman problem); I am interested in going from left to right in the graph at the lowest cost.

Apart from the first time step, there are nine costs to consider at each time step.

Now my question is simply what is this type of problem called?

- It doesn't seem to be the shortest path problem because my path does not need to be contiguous. This means that e.g. $\phi = \{c^0_{q,s_1},c^1_{s_2,s_3} c^2_{s_2,s_1} \}$ is a valid path for my problem setting (if $\phi$ has the lowest cost of going left to right).
- It is not a TSP since I do not need to visit every node (just one per time index), nor do I need to return to the start.
- The Viterbi algorithm perhaps but there is nothing stochastic about my states and I know all the costs but perhaps some other sort of max-sum algorithm?
- I suppose we could use the Bellman–Ford algorithm and just specify the three states at the end, upon which we pick the one with the lowest cost.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your minimum cost "path" is obtained by simply selecting the minimum weight edge in every time step (since the edges need not be connected). I do not believe that there is a special name for this, nor will you need a dedicated algorithm to find this path. In case the edges are connected, then what you are looking for is indeed Viterbi algorithm. It works very generally on any weighted graph with a Trellis structure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. You have indeed understood correctly. Okay point taken about Viterbi (that was actually my first thought but I am struggling to translate my non-stochastic problem to that framework, but perhaps I will try again). I have also seen work showing that it is possible to find shortest paths and longest paths from a given starting vertex in DAGs in linear time by processing the vertices in a topological order, and calculating the path length for each vertex to be the minimum or maximum length. (see: https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap24/24.2/)

Comment: The translation of Viterbi algorithm to the non-stochastic setting is (realtively) straightforward. If you consider the likelihood of a path in the probabilistic setting as its cost, then you see that you can work with costs in a non-probabilistic setting. I can elaborate on this, if you like. The linked algorithm should also work, as it works for arbitrary DAGs (a Trellis is a special DAG). **However**: As I mentioned before, if the edges need not be connected, there is no need for Viterbi processing. Simply loop over each time instant and find the edge with minimum weight in that time step.

Comment: Oh I see, I had not considered that way of approaching it. If you can elaborate I would be very grateful. Please feel free to add it as an answer. This sounds like what I am looking for. I am not quite sure what you mean by 'edges need not be connected' every node needs to be connected with every node at $t-1$ but are not connected to the other within the time-slice $t$ i.e. a trellis.

Comment: I suppose I am confused by the statement that $\phi = \{c^0_{q,s_1},c^1_{s_2,s_3} c^2_{s_2,s_1} \}$ is a valid path. That is, the edges in this path need not be connected. Anyways, I have added an explanation of the Viterbi algorithm in a general weighted graph setting. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah I see, yes that can be confusing. All I meant with $\phi$ was to say that it is a possible path whose edges have the lowest cost so for me that is a "valid path" as I am looking for the 'path' (perhaps that is the wrong word) which has the lowest cost. But it need not be a contiguous route in the traditional sense of the word. There may be another edge, emanating from another state, which has a lower cost than the one we just arrived at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, I think Viterbi algorithm is what you are looking for. I shortly highlight the most important steps needed for computation and how it can be used on a general graph with costly edges.

Define $\mu(i,t)$ as the *cost* of the minimum cost path to the $i$-th state at time $t$ and define $c(i,j,t)$ as the cost of going from state $i$ to state $j$ at time $t$. We will compute $\mu(i,t)$ in an iterative fashion from left to right.

1. Set $\mu(0,0)=0$ for the initial state at time $t=0$.
2. For $t = 1,2,\dots$ and for each state $j$ at time $t$, compute
   $$\mu(j,t) = \min_i \{ \mu(i,t-1)+c(i,j,t-1) \} , $$
   where the minimum is over all states $i$ at time $t-1$ that are connected to the state $(j,t)$.
3. Once you have reached the end, you can backtrack the minimum cost path by identifying at each state the incoming edge with smallest cost.

Note that if you want to spare the backtracking, you can also track the minimum cost path with an auxiliary variable $p(i,t)$ for each state $i$ and time $t$.